# Bootstrap Modal to present search results

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, bootstrap-modal

I would like to present my Google Custom Search Engine results with a Bootstrap modal on my website. I am not sure what to put as the form action (action=""). Currently I am using a separate page on the site.

```
<!-- Search  -->
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-12 search-mob">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input class="search-input col-xs-8" name="q" placeholder="Buscar Mexpro..." size="35" type="text">
          <button title="search" class="gsc-search-button btn btn-primary col-xs-3" size="35" type="submit" value="Inicie" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mobile-search" >Inicie</button>
        </form>
      </div>
<!-- End Search -->
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mobile-search" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mobile-search" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal Content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
          <h2 id="customer-login-header">Buscar en Mexpro</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>  
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to have the searchbox in one div with the results displayed in another div (in your case the div inside the Bootstrap modal). I suppose that you will also need to open the modal before showing the results, right? (This is the tricky part which is not directly supported in the API)

Here is just how you can set the searchbox and the search results in separate containers, in the same page:
http://jsfiddle.net/5r08rbwa/1/
or:
http://jsfiddle.net/xko0zbm6/1/

```
<div id="search-box">
    <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>  
</div>
<div id="search-results-container" style="border:solid 1px red">
    <div>
        Bootstrap Modal (This should be hidden and open just when you press search or enter)
    </div>
    <div id="search-results">
       <gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
    </div>
</div>
```